# How put a space in a string mutiplication?

Tags: python, string

Im doing a project on ppm files where i have to take a image and make it grayscale and flip the image. the method is to take the average of the numbers.

```
P3
255
....
200 200 200
300 300 300
```

Thus the average would be 200, and 300.

```
Averages=[200,300]
for i in averages:
    print(str(i)*3,"\n")
```

this gives me

```
200200200
300300300
```

How do i make it look like the original? My methodology is read each line as a string convert to list then take sum and average of each list then output it like the original. is this good way of going about this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [7]: for i in Averages:
        print(" ".join([str(i)]*3)+"\n")
   ...:  
   ...:  
200 200 200

300 300 300
```

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate your string with a space: -

```
print((str(i) + ' ') * 3, "\n")
```

Or: -

```
print(' '.join([str(i)]*3) + "\n")
```

Comment: this will print a tuple like `('200 200 200 ', '\n')`

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary -- not on py3k -- which is what OP is apparently using since this is how OP does it.

Comment: @RohitJain -- Your old answer was correct.  Your new answer is wrong.

Comment: @mgilson Oh! How should I change it then?

Answer (score 0):

How about reading the python manual for [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting)

Answer (score 0):

If you're really writing 3 elements at a time, why not just do:

```
print '{0} {1] {2}\n'.format(i,i,i)
```

This seems like the most readable way to do it to me...